# MySQL: Multi-pass string concatenation

Tags: mysql, concatenation

All,
  I have a single table in MySQL with the following sample data

> MYDB.DUMMYTABLE

```
SampleColumn
a
b
c
bd
be
bf
cgj
chk
cil
```

I'm trying to achieve the following result set

```
cgj
chk
cil
cgjbd
chkbe
cilbf
```

How would I first select all data who's length equals X (three) then in the next pass concat the same field with all data who's length equals Y (two) to get the output as shown above?

Comment: Can you show what you've got so far - what SQL you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins, for example:

```
select concat(nt2.col1, nt1.col1)
from new_table as nt1
inner join new_table as nt2
   on length(nt2.col1) = 2
where length(nt1.col1) = 3
```

Sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebd5c1/3/0